# How many people were involved in auditing the DAO code? And how many Eth code auditors are there we can goto?

Tags: security, the-dao

How many were responsible for auditing the DAO code? It's understandable that bugs arise from any type of code, but having that the DAO was a big project and that once its created it shouldn't be changed type of deal. I'd imagine the auditing would be top notch an done by veteran Ethereum contract coders.

I'm curious to how many actually went over the code before all this drama. The DAO team paid 250k for a 3 page audit report, but I'd imagine that amount would  be able to hire some very top developers to do code auditing.

My point I want to find out is, how many top Ethereum smart contract devs are there as of 2016-06 that can audit code for other smart contract devs like me? I don't want to create a contract and later find out there was a bug in it that can steal all my funds.